# cout stop working after linker option

Tags: c++, linker, cout

I'm writing a C++ program who takes screenshots. I borrowed the screenshot function from [here](https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/01/12/screenshot-c-win32-api/) and set up a linker option `-mwindows` like the webpage has mentioned, then things happened. `cout` stop showing my texts after I set up the linker option.

Here is my code, before setting up linker options:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std; 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "test\n"; 

    while (true) {
        cout << "test2\n"; 
    }

    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the function `screenshot` along with linker option `-mwindows`:

```
void screenshot(POINT a, POINT b) {
    // copy screen to bitmap
    HDC     hScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC     hDC     = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, abs(b.x-a.x), abs(b.y-a.y));
    HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
    BOOL    bRet    = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, abs(b.x-a.x), abs(b.y-a.y), hScreen, a.x, a.y, SRCCOPY);

    // save bitmap to clipboard
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap);
    CloseClipboard();

    // clean up
    SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hScreen);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
```

What I do know so far is, the program is running good, except cout.

Screenshot is correctly taken, infinite loop is running, and writing files through fstream is also okay if I add it.

And things won't change if I call screenshot anywhere or even never call it (but screenshot is declared), `cout` still shows nothing.

So the problem is not from the `screenshot` function.

`system("pause")` does show its texts if I remove the infinite loop.

It'd be helpful if somebody tell me why the linker option stops `cout` from working. Or do I use linker option in the wrong way? (I think this is nearly impossible because the `screenshot` function works perfectly)

I'm coding with Dev-C++ 5.11. I set up linker options by adding `-mwindows` to **Project Option > Parameters > Linker**.

How can I make cout works normally while with the linker option set up so I can take screenshots? Any information would be appreciated. **Thanks.**

**Edit:** According to my further test, `printf` has the same behavior to `cout`, which shows nothing on console.

Comment: I struggled a little bit in google until I remembered that Dev-C++ is just an IDE and uses compiler? Probably gcc of mingw. Hence, googling "mingw gcc options" finally provided what I was looking for: [3.17.39 i386 and x86-64 Windows Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Windows-Options.html). `-mwindows`: _This option is available for Cygwin and MinGW targets. It specifies that a GUI application is to be generated by instructing the linker to set the PE header subsystem type appropriately._ I assume that this option supresses "normal" console I/O.

Comment: -mwindows makes your probram run in a windows subsystem, which assumes you have a windows GUI in your application and doesn't create a console at all. If you want to have a console you need to make a console application.

Comment: Remember, Windows applications like "Notepad" even don't have a console. (In VS they even have no `main()` but a `WinMain()` instead but I don't know about mingw and gcc. If it is compiling/running with `main()` then it is as it should be...)

Comment: Okay, so it's `-mwindows` that makes my program a windows application and thus lose its console. I'll try again with actual windows application. Thanks!